# php post method undefined index error in database

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "vish";
$database = "android";

$conn= new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$database);

if(!$conn) 
{
    #ie("connection failed" ,mysql_connect_error());
    echo "connection failed";
}
if(!isset($_POST['fname']))
{
    $uname = $_POST['fname'];
}
if(!isset($_POST['lname']))
{
    $lnam = $_POST['lname'];
}
$qur = "
        INSERT INTO test(Username, l_name)
        VALUES ('$uname','$lnam')
        ";
$fetch_qur = "SELECT * FROM test";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$qur);
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$fetch_qur);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
    echo $row['Username'];
    echo $row['l_name'];
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

?>

Its giving me error as  Notice: Undefined index: fname in C:\wamp\www\test\database.php on line 17
as well as for lname.

this code works fine if i use get method .
can anyone explain why this is so
thanks

Comment: What is line 17? Where is your code? Sounds like you are trying to get the result as POST when the variable has been sent over as a GET request. However, as I can't read minds, it's a guess.

Comment: please check it now .. line number 17 is $uname = $_POST['fname'];

Comment: @user3448278 What your if statement does is: `If $_POST["fname"] is NOT  set, then assign it to $uname`

Comment: pl. can you add your html form code here?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>



<form action="database.php" method="POST">
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name= "lname"><br>
<input type="submit" name="sbtn" value="sbutton">




</form>
</body>


</html>

Answer (score 1):

You are checking it wrong. If they are present then set the value. This should be -

```
if(isset($_POST['fname']))
{
    $uname = $_POST['fname'];
}
if(isset($_POST['lname']))
{
    $lnam = $_POST['lname'];
}
```

**Update**

```
if(isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['lname']))
{
    $uname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lnam = $_POST['lname'];
     $qur = "
        INSERT INTO test(Username, l_name)
        VALUES ('$uname','$lnam')
        ";
}
```

Comment: then it says undefined variable at query saying Undefined variable: lnam and uname

Comment: i did that  but it is not going in IF loop and so now it says undefined variable qur when i use $result = mysqli_query($conn,$qur);

Comment: Warning: this code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Consider upgrading to paramterized queries with PDO or mysqli

Comment: @scrowler yup. it is. Needs the security measures.